# Using vlookup match to check existence of number across two tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

**Table To Check**

Each column represents an item, each row below that column represents the ID of one unit of that item. In the below instance, I have 4 apples with IDS 1, 2, 4, 5, and 2 grapes with IDS 3, 8

```
|  Apple  |  Grape  |
|    1    |    8    |
|    5    |    3    |
|    2    |         |
|    4    |         |
```

**Table Master**

Each row represents a unique combination of an item with its ID. The table below represents the same data as above.

```
|    1    |  Apple  |
|    2    |  Apple  |
|    4    |  Apple  |
|    5    |  Apple  |
|    3    |  Grape  |
|    8    |  Grape  |
```

**Problem**

I want to add a column to Table Master, with a formula such that I can confirm that everything in the Table To Check is in fact also present in Table Master, which will also illucidate any items that I have in Table Master but that are NOT in Table To Check and vice versa. I had thought to do this with a simple vlookup match

```
VLOOKUP(E8,"Entire Table To Check",MATCH(F8,"Entire 1st Row in Table To Check",0),FALSE)
```

I'd expect the output to be the value found in Table To Check (i.e., the ID of the item itself, since that's what will be found). But for some reason, the formula is only sometimes working, other times creating an #N/A result. Question: what's the right formula, and why is this one only partially working?

**My result**

```
*New comparison column with formula above             
|    1    |    1    |  Apple  |
|    2    |    2    |  Apple  |
|  #N/A   |    4    |  Apple  |
|  #N/A   |    5    |  Apple  |
|    3    |    3    |  Grape  |
|  #N/A   |    8    |  Grape  |
```

Comment: Do you only ever have two variables or do you have more? For example, could there be a 3rd option called "Lemons" and a 4th called "Oranges"?

Comment: I used your formula and it returned all the IDs for Apple correctly, but gave #N/A for the Grape ID's.  VLOOKUP() looks in the first column of the array and returns the corresponding value from another column that you specify.  The ID's for Grape aren't in the first column of the array.  You can do this with Index/Match.  See the answer below.

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose COrrect, there could be any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: To answer the restated question.

EDIT2: To avoid listing many areas in the reference form of INDEX().

This formula, filled down from E1, uses nested INDEX() functions, along with MATCH() to provide a solution:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(INDEX(A$2:C$5,,MATCH(G2,A$1:C$1,0)),MATCH(F2,INDEX(A$2:C$5,,MATCH(G2,A$1:C$1,0)),0)),"No ID Found")`

[image]

How it works:  The second INDEX() returns one column of Item ID's from the array A2:C5, specifically the column with the heading that matches the item name in Column G.  That column is given by this portion of the formula:

`INDEX(A$2:C$5,,MATCH(G2,A$1:C$1,0))`

The first INDEX() uses that column as its array with the row_num given by the second MATCH().  That MATCH() looks up the ID from Column F in the same column of Item ID's used by the first INDEX(), and it uses the same portion of the formula to specify that column.

Finally, the whole formula is wrapped in IFERROR() to note any listed ID's that weren't found.

Comment: I can't use an IF statement though, because I need to account for any number of potential header types (e.g., Apple, Grape, Peach, Strawberry, Pear, etc.)

Comment: Sometimes, if you *clearly* define your problem, you can get an acceptable answer.  See the edited response above.

Comment: Hmmm, so there isn't a solution where I would NOT have to, in the formula, define the columns (as in the inner index)? Where I could just select the entire table without listing `A$2:A$5,B$2:B$5,C$2:C$5`

Comment: Seems like there *should* be a way to reference a 2-D array and return just one column of it, then use that in an Index/Match. I'm not at my computer now, but, I'll take another look at it tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, it works.  See the (hopefully *last*) edit above.